# checking different data value in a same column mysql query?

Tags: mysql

```
id_detail_item id_item   id_detail_item_name
1              1         abc 
2              1         abcd
3              1         cde
4              3         zki
5              3         zkr
```

How to check if there are two different data in "id_detail_item_name" in the same "id_item"?

I've tried the following, but got an error:

```
SELECT id_item FROM table_detail_item WHERE id_detail_item_name='abc' AND id_detail_item_name='abcd';
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the AND operator means both conditions must be met.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_detail_item 
WHERE id_item = '1' 
AND id_detail_item_name IN ('abc', 'abcd');
```

Comment: You can also use id_detail_item_name in ('abc','abcd')

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This only checks if `id_detail_item_name` is either 'abc' or 'abcd'. What if `id_detail_item_name`s are 'abc' and 'cde'?

Comment: this seems will got the same result like using 'or'

Answer (score 0):

This should list all entries with at least two different `id_detail_item_name` for  `id_item`

```
SELECT id_item, MIN(id_detail_item_name) nam1,max(id_detail_item_name) nam2 
FROM table_detail_item 
GROUP by id_item HAVING MIN(id_detail_item_name) nam1<MAX(id_detail_item_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select id_item
  from (
              select min(id_detail_item_name) mmin
                   , max(id_detail_item_name) mmax
                from table_detail_item
            group by id_item
       ) agg
 where agg.mmin <> agg.mmax
     ;
```